# Integrating Javascript and Jquery in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to integrate this javascript from the JSFiddle into the html page.
The code might not be pretty ( and it's not ) but it does the trick :).

The problem is that the code works in JSFiddle but I cannot implement it in a single html document. This might be the stupidest question but I need help.

Here is the JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nhzr0kyb/

Javascript:

```
$('#never1').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).siblings('#less1, #lunar1, #saptamanal1, #week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $('#less1, #lunar1, #saptamanal1').attr('disabled', false);   
             $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true); 
        }
    });

$('#less1').change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});

 $('#lunar1').change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});   



  $('#saptamanal1').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});

 $("#checkbox").prop("checked", false).click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
 $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);
 });


      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.mutuallyexclusive').click(function () {
              checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
              $('.mutuallyexclusive:checked').each(function () {
                  $(this).attr('checked', false);                   
              });
              $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
              $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);

          });
      });

      $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.checkbox1').click(function () {
              checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
              $('.checkbox1:checked').each(function () {
                  $(this).attr('checked', false);
              });
              $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
              $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);
          });
      });
```

Thanks in advance,
Iosif

Comment: What have you done to find out why it does not work in other pages? What *exactly* "does not work"? Why is some of your code inside `$(document).ready(function() {...});` and other is not?

Comment: show your pages markup on devtools

Comment: this is my page markup

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=<#Charset>">
  <title>OpinionWorld</title>
  <script>
   <!--
   function doOnLoad() {}
   function doOnUnLoad() {}
   //-->
      </script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <link href="http://www.ssisurveys.com/OW/survey/css/OW2007.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 </head>

Comment: I've added the correct JS FIddle

Answer (score 1):

To be sure that you code is the same on jsfiddle, on Frameworks & Extensions section choose "no wrap in head", that's the difference.

[image]

Now you can manage to on load event instead of leaving jsfiddle doing this for you.

And always add ready event to your code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

If you dont do that you some errors can occur.

Comment: This makes sense. I've copied the code in a new JSFiddle and it didn't worked because it was on other framework and extension. In the bigger picture, I need to integrate that in a bigger html file. Would it be better if I can attach the file somewhere so you guys can see what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#noneAboveCheck').change(function () {
        $('#noneAbove').toggle(this.checked);
    }).change();

    $('#incarcerated, #support').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', true);
        } else {
            $('#noneAboveCheck').attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
 
//all of the other code
 
('#never1').change(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
            $(this).siblings('#less1, #lunar1, #saptamanal1, #week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
        } else {
            $('#less1, #lunar1, #saptamanal1').attr('disabled', false);   
             $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true); 
        }
    });

$('#less1').change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});

 $('#lunar1').change(function () {
    $(this).siblings('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
});   

$('#saptamanal1').change(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("checked")) {
        $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});

 $("#checkbox").prop("checked", false).click(function() {
     $(this).siblings('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17:checkbox').not(this).removeAttr('checked');
 $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);
 });


          $('.mutuallyexclusive').click(function () {
              checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
              $('.mutuallyexclusive:checked').each(function () {
                  $(this).attr('checked', false);                   
              });
              $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
              $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);

          });

          $('.checkbox1').click(function () {
              checkedState = $(this).attr('checked');
              $('.checkbox1:checked').each(function () {
                  $(this).attr('checked', false);
              });
              $(this).attr('checked', checkedState);
              $('#week11, #week12, #week13, #week14, #week15, #week16, #week17').attr('disabled', true);
          });
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p><input id="noneAboveCheck" type="checkbox" />None of the above</p>
<div id="noneAbove" class="hidden">
    <p><input id="incarcerated" type="checkbox" /></p>
    <p><input id="support" type="checkbox" />Blah Blah</p>
</div>
```

did you remember to add jquery to your html  tag?
[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)

also, like Felix Kling said put everything into one document ready function. and you only need one document ready you currently have two.
[jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: Yes, I've remembered to add it, as I replied to maioman. I've put all the code inside $document.ready(function() { ... all that code }); , removed the two document ready from the two functions, added in a <script type="text/javascript> </script> tag but it's still not working

Comment: try the code i added.  it works for me. hope it helps.

Comment: I do not really see your code, but I've changed the JSFiddle ( I've put the wrong one the first time ). This is the correct JSFiddle, it works, it does what it is supposed to, but I don't know how to integrate into the whole HTML document ( yes, it is more that on the JSFiddle page ).

Answer (score 0):

[html files ( source + test ) available](http://www.fileshare.ro/e31706860)

I'm out of ideas. If someone wants to look at the file and may see a way to include the code from the JSfiddle, please do. Or put a hint, or something. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something pretty simple here.

Thank you,
Iosif

Answer (score 0):

in order to integrate this into your HTML document you must do a couple of things.

1. first you must link to the jQuery library. there are a few ways you can do this but the easiest (and maybe the best) is to link to it though Google. you can do this by adding this code `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>` right BEFORE the end of your `<body></body>` tag.  note: there are other version of the jQuery library that you may need to use instead depending on your jQuery code. i just picked this one because it is the latest.
   (you can read about the other way to link to the jQuery library [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)
2. now you have to tell jQuery to run your code when the HTML document has loaded. you do this by wrapping your jQuery code in a `<script></script>` tag and placing it right before the end of your `<body></body>` tag. it must go AFTER the code you added in step one. (you could also link to an external .js file that would contain your jQuery code without the `<script></script>` tags. you can read more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp).)

having said that, you may want to take a closer look at both your HTML and jQuery code. they seem a little problematic to me but with a little more research you will get there. i'm new at this too but the more i research the easier it gets. good luck from one noob to another.

by the way, i have heard a lot of better coders rip on the w3schools that i linked to but i think it is ok for the simple stuff that we are trying to learn.